# Intellisense in VS 2012 RC not working for SignalR classes

Tags: intellisense, visual-studio-2012, signalr

I have imported SignalR Nuget package and SignalR sample is working well in my project. But even after having all required using statements I can't get the intellisense working for the classes in SignalR (like Hub class).

Comment: have you imported teh signalR namespace?

Comment: Yes, I have imported all the namespaces and my solution builds successfully and runs successfully. Only problem is with the intellisense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at the SignalR documentation [here](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Hubs)
the Hub.Caller and Clients are dynamic in nature.
[dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598922.aspx) is a new keyword added in .Net 4 and dosent support compile time checking so you cannot get intellisense for dynamic objects. all the dynamic objects are checked at runtime only. so even if you your self create a dynamic object like

```
dynamic d = new ExpandoObject();
```

and try to do this `"d."`. you wont get any intellisense because the framework dosent know whats all is present in the dynamic object. and will be discovered only at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

The hubs proxy is dynamically generated at runtime, so you won't get any intellisense for it.

You can use Hubify.exe (see Hubify-section on http://weblogs.asp.net/davidfowler/archive/2012/06/10/signalr-0-5-1-released.aspx ) to generate a static javascript-file.

Or you can create your own T4-Template that does the same thing. See: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/106

**Update:**

Regarding intellisense for C#
You won't get intellisense for `Clients` and `Caller`, since they are dynamic.

> Absence of compile-time type checking leads to the absence of IntelliSense as well. Because the C# compiler doesn't know the type of the object, it can't enumerate its properties and methods. This problem might be solved with additional type inference, as is done in the IronPython tools for Visual Studio, but for now C# doesn't provide it.
>   http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2011/02/01/understanding-the-dynamic-keyword-in-c4.aspx

```
public class Chat : Hub 
  {
      public void Send(string message) 
      {
          // No intellisense for addMessage, sorry
          Clients.addMessage(message);
      }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mats. Here I'm not talking about JS. I have the problem with the C# classes. Do you have any idea why that's happening.

Comment: Could you update your example with code that should be giving you intellisense but don't?

Comment: Following is the sample code. public class Chat : Hub
    {
        public Chat()
        {
        }

        public void Send(string message)
        {
            Clients.addMessage(message);
        }
    }